# Time data does not match formatting

Tags: python, datetime

Here is my code and I am getting the following error:
I am failing to see what is wrong with ['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'] considering that my date and time are formatted exactly like that. Maybe it is an issue elsewhere? I tried changing my formatting around a little bit, but to no success.

[image]

Comment: Please paste code as text, not screenshots of it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, but why do you want to use brackets? Just write:

```
newTime.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(elem), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

If you want to add in newTime array an array, you need to use:

```
newTime.append([datetime.datetime.strptime(str(elem), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")])
```